# Is it possible to modify compopts dynamically from an external completion command?

Tags: bash, go, bash-completion

I am writing a bash completion program in Golang. In fact, the program is its own completion program as it looks for the COMP_LINE environment variable and if it is present, it outputs the completion options, and if not, just proceeds to run the main program.

The completion is then installed with the following:

```
complete -C /path/to/my-program my-program
```

This works well. For most of my completions, I want a space to be added after the word has been completed, however for a few flags I do not want this to occur.

When completion is defined, you can set a `-o nospace` option to omit the trailing space when completing a word. However then all completions that need a space have to have one added explicitly to the completion word list.

Is there any way that my program can modify the complete opts dynamically based on what completion it is returning? Is this exposed as an environment variable that a completion command could set?

I would like to avoid having to append a space to all other completions just to avoid one in the edge case for the one flag I don't want that to happen on.

Comment: is it more flexible to use `complete -F _my_program` and then in `_my_program` it can call `/path/to/my-program`? so you have access to all bash things in the func `_my_program`.

Comment: @pynexj I thought of that. The downside is that the library I'm using to implement this completion installs it's own complete line. Keeping that complete line simple is really nice. But I'm coming to the conclusion that there is no other way to achieve this aside from making all completions have the nospace option and then adding the space explicitly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My Perl framework ([Perinci::CmdLine](https://metacpan.org/pod/Perinci::CmdLine)) also does the same: the scripts are their own completion, activated using complete -C SCRIPTNAME SCRIPTNAME (when the script is in PATH). Completing using an external command has its pro's and con's compared to using shell function. To solve the problem you encountered, I output a dummy answer with an extra space. Since there are more than one answer, bash no longer automatically adds a space. So instead of just returning (in JSON notation):

```
["-o"]
```

you return:

```
["-o","-o "]
```

I also use this trick when doing path completion. To allow user completing a path by "drilling down", when there is a single directory match I output:

```
["dirname/","dirname/ "]
```

so the user can Tab again to drill down inside path instead of getting a space after "dirname/ " and having to backspace and Tab again.

Comment: Wow thank you. This is exactly what I need. Super simple to add and doesn't require modifying the existing package. Once I test this I will accept this answer.

Comment: Does this list two completion options when the user pressed tab tab

Comment: Yes, it will show something ugly like: `-o    -o\ `. But usually the goal of not adding space is so that user can press Tab again to do further completion. So in the second example of my answer, if user types "dirn" and presses Tab, she will be presented with `["dirname/","dirname/ "]` (note that when printing these answers to stdout you have to escape the space), bash would immediately complete to "dirname/". If user Tabs again, I will present more answers of files/dirs under "dirname/". If you are not providing further completion, why prevent the automatic space in the first place?